# Get information about Audio Devices on Windows 10 IoT Core

Tags: c#, powershell, audio, windows-10-iot-core

I'm looking for a solution to find audio device endpoint settings on Windows 10 IoT Core.

I especially want following information:

- Number of supported channels (eg. 1, 2, 6)
- Supported frequencies (eg. 44 100 Hz, 48 000 Hz etc.)
- Supported bit depth (eg. 16 bit, 24 bit etc.)

I am able to access device name, friendly name and GUID. How can I gather the rest of the information I need and eventually even change it?

I can use remote PowerShell for this or a local C# UWP app that later on will comunicate with remote PC to send this information. I could even fake the call to IoT Device Portal, if there is no other way to do this properly - but I haven't been able to find it there anyway.

What I've tried so far:
 - Running `IoTCoreAudioControlTool l` in remote PowerShell session
 - Running `Get-ChildItem hklm:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\MMDevices\Audio\Render`

But both of these return at most the GUID of the endpoints only and not the information I need.

Comment: You may need to use one of the [Core Audio APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370802(v=vs.85).aspx).  If you want to use .Net or PowerShell, I think that means you'll have to use PInvoke to access them.  The API for devices seems to be [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370805(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Please refer to the sample [**WindowsAudioSession**](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/WindowsAudioSession) for more information.